# DataNodes Hard disk drive

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to know the maximum number of hard disk drive can I put in each DataNode and the size of these disk.

In my case I have 60TB of data so that storage space is 180TB (after replication), if the size of hard drive disk is 2TB and their number is 4 (8TB per DataNode/ 5,6 dedicated space).

I get 32 DataNodes.

Is what I'm doing possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for server-sizing information, not a programming problem.

Comment: where can I put this question ?

Comment: I'd guess [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm asked this question here because I found it in **Cloudera Administrator Training for Apache Hadoop** part 7 **Planning Your Hadoop Cluster**

Comment: And why does that mean you should ask it on a site about *programming* questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the article in the link below to understand some best practices in Hadoop world

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/16763/cheat-sheet-and-tips-for-a-custom-install-of-horto.html